# DevDemon Updater error: The configuration file updater_config.php does not exist

Tags: updating, devdemon-updater

I'm trying to use DevDemon Updater (3.2.9) to upgrade EE from 2.5.5 to 2.6.1. It uploads the ZIP file just fine, runs the backups, gets through "Copying Installer files", and then stops with this error:

> The configuration file updater_config.php does not exist.

However, looking in \third_party\updater\config, I see that updater_config.php DOES exist.

What does this error mean?

Comment: What are the file permissions set to on updater_config.php?

Comment: Are you using local or ftp transfer mode?

Comment: Set file permissions to 777; no change. Using the local file transfer mode.